# Unable to insert records on sqlite on a Linux environment

Tags: centos, files, permissions, php, sqlite

I tested a simple `Php` program using `Sqlite3` instead of `mySQL` on my own computer and it works fine. What the program does is simple insert of record into a certain table. Now, when I try to do that on a remote web server running on `Linux` (CentOS) with `Sqlite3` enabled it does not work.

I thought at first it was simply a file permission issue since my `Sqlite` file had an initial permissions of **644** so I changed it to **646** then **767** both to no avail.

The `Php` version by the way on web server is a little bit dated, namely, `Php` **5.1.6** but on my local PC it is **5.5.11**.

This is the sample code that I ran on both servers.

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:test.db');

$lastname = "Doe";
$firstname = "John";
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (Lastname,Firstname) VALUES (:lastname,:firstname)";

$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':lastname'=>$lastname,
                  ':firstname'=>$firstname));
```

I tried a simple query on a **sqlite3** database on the webserver by the way and it works.

So, could this be a simple `Php` version issue or some elevated rights that I need on Linux?

I cannot by the way change the `php.ini` so forgo that possible direction for the moment. And I don't have any choice of having a new `Php` version on that server since I use it for free.

I tried to asked this same question SO but to no avail so I am trying my luck here.

Comment: Try getting an exception on error with `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: @meuh Thanks I'll try this one and I'll get back to you if I have something. GOD bless.

Comment: @meuh I tested and it has the same unfavorable result :-( Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: but did it log any error messages in a file somewhere (/var/log/...)?

Comment: Honestly @meuh I have no permission to view those files.

Comment: You can add into the start of your php code `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` then errors and warning will be written into the returned web page.